# Pythonic way to find lowest value in dictionary with list as values

Tags: python-3.x

I have a dictionary with values as list. In the given dictionary I want to find the lowest number (for every item in the list considering the value at index 0). I have written a script and works fine, but I am looking for a more Pythonic way to solve this.

```
c={'Apple': ['210-219', '246-255'], 'Orange': ['159-161', '202-204', '207-209', '209-211', '220-222', '238-240', '245-247', '261-263']}
loweststart=[]
for ckey, cvalue in c.items():
    for i in cvalue:
        
        print (i.split('-')[0])
        start=int(i.split('-')[0])
        loweststart.append(start)
        
print (loweststart)
print ('The lowest:',min(loweststart))
```

Comment: Is there a reason that you are using `c.items()` to get the (ckey, cvalue) pairs from c, using cvalue and ignoring the ckey, instead of just using `c.values()` to get just the values?

Comment: There is no reason. I just wrote it this way. you are right. Just calling c.values() should do the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `min` function with a generator expression that iterates through the items in the sub-lists of the dict and outputs the integer values of the first tokens in the strings:

```
min(int(s[:s.find('-')]) for l in c.values() for s in l)
```

Using a generator expression is more efficient because it avoids the need to create a temporary list to store all the values extracted from the sub-lists.

Comment: Using the `str.split` method is less efficient since it creates a temporary list of strings when only the first item is needed. With the `str.find` method we can slice the string directly and efficiently.

Comment: Oh! Thank you. I was not aware of str.find. Will use it next time

Comment: Thank you all for your kind help.

Answer (score 1):

**A pythonic way:**

```
min_list = [int(element.split('-')[0]) for value in c.values() for element in value]
print(min(min_list))
```

Comment: This answer forgets to convert the string to int. It needs to be modified like this `int(element.split('-')[0])` and it should then work.

Answer (score 0):

As much as I hate the adjective Pythonic, this would seem to qualify:

```
min([min([int(i.split('-')[0]) for i in ci[1]]) for ci in c.items()])
```

(The logic is slightly different than the original, in that it finds the minimum of *each* list, then the minimum of those minima, but the end result is the same.)

Comment: Why do you hate the adjective ````pythonic````? The alternative is surely just poorly formatted/difficult to read code

Comment: @7koFnMiP Depends on how you define Pythonic.

Comment: @7koFnMiP are you suggesting that the nested list comprehension above is clearer (and easier for a later maintainer to follow) than the for loops in the OPs question? I agree it is shorter.

Comment: If something is written in a less clear way then that doesn't meet the definition of pythonic. List comprehensions can clearly represent loops concisely but if it's overly complex, as in this example, surely it stops being pythonic rather than pythonicity stopping being clear

Comment: I should also not that I prefer descriptivist approaches to definitions